# Sharepoint 2019 autochanges links from file://fs01/Public/Share to file:///Public/Share when editing a site page

Tags: sharepoint-server, file, 2019, edit

Sharepoint 2019 autochanges links from file://fs01/Public/Share to file:///Public/Share when editing a site page. Seems to be something simple, yet I can't crack this one down, please find the screenshots below, any help appreciated.

[image: desc2]

[image: desc1]

Comment: I can't reproduce on a classic Publishing site using IE 11. What PU do you have installed on the farm?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2019 and i cannot reproduce your issue.

For your issue, try to do the following:

Try to remove the link and insert the link again and compare the results.

Try to insert another link in another page and check whether the issue exists.

Open the page in another browser and compare the results.

Comment: I created a new test page with the following source:"<a href="file://fs01/Public/Share">0010 Correspondence</a>" however it still replaces the link with "<a href="file:///Public/Share">0010 Correspondence</a>". The use case is that there are 200 pages which were restored from SharePoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2019 using Veeam Explorer for Sharepoint and every link which had "file://fs01/Share" got replaced with "file:///Share" at first we though there was an issue with Veeam, however when we tried to edit the page manually the behavior described was reproduced.